# JSF upload file twice

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I have the following code:

```
<h:inputFile value="#{myBean.file}">
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-plus"></i>
    <f:ajax execute="@all" render="formOne formTwo" listener="#
    {myBean.parseDoc}" />
    <span>Upload</span>
</h:inputFile>
```

Here is the bean

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class OneTimeBean {

    private Part file; 

    public void parseDoc(AjaxBehaviorEvent e) throws IOException, Exception {
        //some logic
    }
}
```

When I try to upload two different files everything is okay. But when I try to upload the same file with the same name twice the program is not entering the parseDoc method at all :/ I dont have any idea why this occurs :///

Comment: Why don't you use code snippet from primefaces showcase? [file upload](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/basic.xhtml)

Comment: If you don't change the inputfile, why should an ajax event fire? Or does file a, file b and file a again also not work?

Comment: Why should it not be possible to upload the same file twice? You cannot upload a file once and process the Part (or its `InputStream`) twice. It has to be done in the same request.